# Sqlite with Entity framework - Error: "Specified cast is not valid"

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, sqlite

The field type is money, if I put a '0' or a '1' in the field I get this error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

 at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.VerifyType(Int32 i, DbType typ)
 at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.GetBoolean(Int32 i)

 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

This is from the model designer:

```
<Property Name="Amount" Type="decimal" Precision="53" />
```

====

```
    <EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty:=False, IsNullable:=True)>
<DataMemberAttribute()>
Public Property Amount() As Nullable(Of Global.System.Decimal)
    Get
        Return _Amount
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Nullable(Of Global.System.Decimal))
        OnAmountChanging(Value)
        ReportPropertyChanging("Amount")
        _Amount = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value)
        ReportPropertyChanged("Amount")
        OnAmountChanged()
    End Set
End Property

Private _Amount As Nullable(Of Global.System.Decimal)
Private Partial Sub OnAmountChanging(value As Nullable(Of Global.System.Decimal))
End Sub

Private Partial Sub OnAmountChanged()
End Sub
```

Code to get error:

```
 Dim Query = From c In EnData.Transactions Where c.TranID = 660 ' this tran is the amount 0

        For Each tran In Query 'Error here

        Next
```

Comment: I added some code, is this what your looking for?

Comment: can you show us the code where you're setting the amount?

Comment: I'm not setting it yet. I get the error just by doing a simple query "Dim Q = (From e in myContext.Transaction)"

Comment: @Ezi show part of the code there error is happening, and all code related to that part.

Comment: Are you sure the 'Amount' field is a decimal type in the sqlite database? If you store '2' or '42' in the Amount field your code works?

Comment: Yes its a dec. field, and '2' or '42' causes the error too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Got the problem... its not the amount field. an other column which is a bit type, some times it doesn't like the way I wrote the false or true. that causes the problem.

The solution is to use 1 for true and 0 for false, that is always ok.

Comment: Using EF 6.02 and SQLite 1.0.91 this is still happening, just wasted a day because of this. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I write SQL for Microsoft SQL Server. If the following example is invalid for `SqLite`, kindly let me know and I will remove this answer.

**Question:** What is: `StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value)`? Is this a custom function? If so, could you define that?

Perhaps modifying your VB code to do the following help:

```
Public Property Amount() As System.Decimal
    Get
        Return _Amount
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Global.System.Decimal)
        OnAmountChanging(Value)
        ReportPropertyChanging("Amount")
        If value = 0 Then
          _Amount = 0.00M
        Else If value = 1 Then
          _Amount = 1.00M
        Else
          _Amount = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value)
        End If
        ReportPropertyChanged("Amount")
        OnAmountChanged()
    End Set
End Property
```

Typically, I prefer to place the "most true" case on the top, but my VB skills are not so good.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is automatically generated code, there is no Null problem here.

Comment: @Ezi: Updated code to test for 1 and 0. Perhaps `SQLite` or `SetValidValue` is interpreting the input as an `Integer` or a `Boolean`. The value indicated above should force the 1 and 0 to a double (M for Money).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, please see the edit in the question. I found where the problem is.